# Getting Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found error in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

While running one of my Flutter Apps in ios simulator, I am getting this error[image]

I was using Xcode 14.3.1. I was expecting to build the app and run in the ios simulator. This error. I have already tried all these stuffs like pod deintegrate, pod install & all & Nothing seems to be working.